# Are the Primeval anomalies localised on Great Britain?

Tags: primeval

It seems like the anomalies allow travel through both time and space (e.g. the Ancient Egyptian creature in S3E01), but I don't recall any mention of any anomalies in the current day outside of Britain.

Has this been addressed in the show?  Either by saying that there are other anomalies (are there then other ARCs?) or that they are localised to the general area covered by the show?

Obviously the out-of-universe explanation for the anomalies being in Britain is that it's a UK production.  I'm wondering if I missed an in-universe explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a series of Primeval spin-off books, known as the *Older Novels* series, which are based all around the notion that anomalies can open in other parts of the world, besides Great Britain.

These *Older Novels* are, indeed, considered to be canonical, within the Primeverse. The ARC Team travels to Peru, Guns Island (an island off of the coast of Ireland), Siberia, and South Africa.

Answer (score 6):

Well there is talk of a Primeval [spin off](http://danowen.blogspot.com/2010/08/primeval-goes-canadian.html) show based in another country to complement the original series. That would seem to imply that anomalies can exist elsewhere.

In-universe explanation: their anomaly detector doesn't have the range to detect anomalies outside the UK. Also stories of strange creatures exist all over the world not just in the UK, like Big Foot or Mokele-Mbembe lending credence to anomalies occurring elsewhere

Comment: Stories of strange creatures could explain some incursions, but not if one of the future predators or some other extremely dangerous creature emerged in a densely populated city.  If they are widespread, then someone needs to be handling the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen a solid "they do or don't appear elsewhere" comment.  But there are details so far which could be lightly spoilerish.  Since I can't find any way to hide text, I'll be vague.  ^_^

By the end of season two, there is a larger story emerging which seems to indicate the anomalies may be triggered.  This would mean they would be localized wherever the creator wants them.

Comment: You can mark spoiler text by starting a line with >! (I've seen all episodes in S1-S4 BTW, although S1/S2 was a long time ago, and I haven't read any of the books).

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of it in season 1.  I just started season 2 last night, so I can't speak to the rest of it.

**Update:**

During the first episode of Season 3, the team investigates an anomaly which occurs inside a 'Sun Cage' in the British Museum.  The Sun Cage is an ancient Egyptian statue made out of magnetite.  According to the hieroglyphs on it, its purpose is to contain an anomaly, which would mean that anomalies happened in Egypt thousands of years before.

Comment: I mention that in the first sentence of the question :)

Comment: @Tony Yes, you do :)  But the fact that the statue was built by Ancient Egyptians for the express purpose of containing anomolies, indicates that anomolies occurred in Ancient Egypt.

Comment: @Tony Hrm.  Whoops, I just noticed your 'present day' comment.  :-/